# Mongodb BI Connector & Tableau: Error while trying to run mongosqld

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, business-intelligence, connector

I'm trying to connect Tableau to MongoDB using MongoDB BI Connector and this instruction (version 2.1 (current)):

https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/v2.1/installation/

but I get an error in step 5:

```
mongosqld --schema=schema.drdl --mongo-uri=mongodb://localhost:27017

2017-07-04T15:19:44.032+0200 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] mongosqld version: v2.1.0
2017-07-04T15:19:44.032+0200 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] git version: 518180ba2c547d2cc6071f955d98ec6de730c0c9
2017-07-04T15:19:44.032+0200 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] arguments: --mongo-uri mongodb://localhost:27017 --schema schema.drdl
2017-07-04T15:19:44.032+0200 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for mongosqld.
2017-07-04T15:19:44.032+0200 I CONTROL    [initandlisten]
2017-07-04T15:19:44.038+0200 I NETWORK    [initandlisten] connecting to mongodb at mongodb://localhost:27017
error starting server: listen unix /tmp/mysql.sock: bind: address already in use
```

`mongosqld` is installed properly:

```
mongosqld --version

mongosqld version v2.1.0
git version: 518180ba2c547d2cc6071f955d98ec6de730c0c9
```

also, my `mongod` is running and working with the default port (27017) by running this command:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR-1T/
```

Do you have any idea that what's the problem with running `mongosqld`?

Comment: Does `ps ax | grep mongosqld` show results before you start? Then the service might be already started.

Comment: @tobi6 Yes, as it shows mongosqld is running! I tried to kill it but when I do your command again, it shows another process for mongosqld again!

Comment: Then I suppose you can jump over that step since mongosqld is running already.

Comment: @tobi6 I tried it, too but Tableau isn't able to connect to this mysql server!

Comment: @tobi6 The result of your command is something like this: `29703 pts/0     S+      0:00 grep --color=auto mongosqld`

Comment: Hehe... that is the grep command from `ps ax | grep mongosqld`. This line should be ignored. Please check why it says `/tmp/mysql.sock` since you are trying to start mongosqldb and not mysqldb.

Comment: @tobi6 Oh! I made a mistake!

Comment: @tobi6 And it's mysql.sock since `mongosqld` accepts incoming requests from a MySQL client and proxies the requests to `mongod` instance.

Comment: Might be required then to check if a mysql instance is running already? `ps ax | grep mysqld`.

Comment: @tobi6 I just moved the `mysql.sock` file and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the problem was with the `mysql.sock` file. So, you can remove it or move it somewhere else and try executing the command again. At least in my case, the problem is solved and `mongosqld` is running! Maybe it helps someone in the future and maybe someone let us know what's the exact reason!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aboozar.

Mongosqld will - by default - attempt to bind to unix domain sockets on OSes where that exists. The error you saw above is an indication that some other process was already bound to `mysql.sock` - this could have been another instance of mongosqld or a mysqld server.

To reliably avoid situations like this in the future, you can start mongosqld with the additional flag `--noUnixSocket`.